# Fetching Data through API from Delta Exchange

Tags: python, api

I am trying to fetch the data from api of delta exchange using this:

```
import requests
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.get('https://api.delta.exchange/v2/history/sparklines', params={
  'C-BTC-60000-090421': 'string'
}, headers = headers)

print(r.json())
```

Getting the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-172739fa579b> in <module>()
      8 }, headers = headers)
      9 
---> 10 print(r.json())

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Check the content of the response with `r.content` instead of `r.json()`. I believe that API is down right now. Cause I'm just getting `Internal Server Error`

Comment: @TimWoocker Can you please put the code you used?

Comment: Just open the url in your browser with the params appended: https://api.delta.exchange/v2/history/sparklines?C-BTC-60000-090421=string

Comment: seem to work fine now.